# Apache httpd reverse proxy returns SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG when HTTP redirects to HTTPS

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, reverse-proxy

I am setting up an Apache v2.4 httpd reverse proxy for another server hosting Atlassian Confluence.

The proxy's private IP address is 10.0.0.77, its public IP address is 77.77.77.77, and a DNS A record maps the public IP to `confluence.example.com`.

There is a NAT in place:

- 77.77.77.77:10080 -> 10.0.0.77:80
- 77.77.77.77:10443 -> 10.0.0.77:443

which is necessary because the proxy's public IP address is used also for other services.

Name resolution on the proxy is done via `/etc/hosts`, which maps `confluence.example.com` to 10.0.0.9, the private IP of the Confluence server.

Here's `/etc/httpd/conf.d/confluence.conf` (as you see, it also does a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName confluence.example.com
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost off
    SetEnv force-proxy-request 1
    SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
    ProxyPass        "/" "http://confluence.example.com:8090/" 
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://confluence.example.com:8090/"
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName confluence.example.com
    ServerSignature On
        <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Proxy>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    # SSL cipher suite shortened for clarity
    SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384"
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/httpd/ssl/example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example.key
    SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/httpd/ssl/example.crt
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on 
    ProxyPass        "/" "http://confluence.example.com:8090/" 
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://confluence.example.com:8090/"
</VirtualHost>
```

When accessing http://confluence.example.com:10080 (or even http://77.77.77.77:10080) from a browser, the URL changes to https://confluence.example.com:10080 but, instead of showing the Confluence login page, this error is returned:

> Secure Connection Failed
>   An error occurred during a connection to 77.77.77.77:10080. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

This is what is logged (DEBUG level) to the http access log:

```
33.33.33.33 - - [17/Sep/2018:17:06:59 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
33.33.33.33 - - [17/Sep/2018:17:06:59 +0200] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 226 "-" "-"
```

and to the http error log:

```
[Mon Sep 17 17:11:58.095085 2018] [core:debug] [pid 23120] protocol.c(1271): [client 33.33.33.33:49745] AH00566: request failed: malformed request line
```

I have set up separate https access and error logs, nothing is logged there.
As you might have guessed, 33.33.33.33 is my outgoing public IP.

Accessing https://confluence.example.com:10443 works fine.

The same config works on another Apache v2.2 reverse proxy.

Any hint?

Comment: Well yes, 77.77.77.77:10080 speaks http, not https, that's why you get a protocol-level error in your browser. Beyond that, my brain is stuck in the additional knots introduced by NAT. I think you'd want to end up at http*s*://77.77.77.77:10443, no?

Comment: Yes.  I don't like the NAT solution neither but apparently we can't do otherwise -- as I said, that public IP address is also used by the old 2.2 proxy.

Comment: OK, let's try to boil this down a little bit, eliminate variables: all the proxy lines in Vhost 80 can go, since you just want to redirect. RewriteRule can have the [R] flag just to be sure. ([The docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) say "hostname matches" when I believe it should be "hostname and protocol match" in the "Absolute URL" description.)

Comment: VHost 443: your Proxypass/ProxypassReverse should be able to use the 10.0.0.9 explicitly, since you have `ProxyPreserveHost on`, saves a bit of confusion with the `/etc/hosts` entry.

Comment: Yeah, this would be easier if you could stick another virtual IP on the interface… I suspect you'll end up putting the :10443 in the redirect explicitly, because NAT shouldn't look at the message content at that level. I don't see why you didn't end up at 77.77.77.77:443 then with your current config, though, because `%{HTTP_HOST}` shouldn't include the port.

Comment: I have edited the question.  Actually I am trying to land on https://confluence.example.com:10443 (using the FQDN and not the IP to avoid SSL domain mismatch); good news is that this URL works fine when accessed directly.  I'll test your suggestion about `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Also, note that the NAT will be removed once the whole stuff goes to production.

Comment: I'd try making that RewriteRule point at `https://%{HTTP_HOST}:10443%{REQUEST_URI}`, that might just do it. Everything else is just trying to simplify 
 because I get confused easily. ;-)

Comment: Modifying the RewriteRule as you suggested causes this error to be shown on the webpage: *Corrupted Content Error - The site at http://confluence.example.com:10080/ has experienced a network protocol violation that cannot be repaired. The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this for my Tomcat instances. (Formerly Confluence, now XWiki.)

1. The http → https vHost is a straight redirect, no proxies.
2. The https vHost manages the proxy rewrites for Tomcat, knowing that the URI has a sane pattern.

Here's a (slightly) edited version of my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin web@example.com

        ServerName confluence.example.com

        DocumentRoot /home/www/confluence.example.com/docroot


        # Global protection
        #
        <Directory />
                Options none
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>


        # Send users to canonical website
        #
        Redirect / https://confluence.example.com/


        # Logging
        #
        ServerSignature On
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /home/www/confluence.example.com/logs/%Y/%m/%d/public-error.log"
        CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /home/www/confluence.example.com/logs/%Y/%m/%d/public-access.log" combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin web@example.com

        ServerName confluence.example.com

        DocumentRoot /home/www/confluence.example.com/docroot
        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8


        # Global protection
        #
        <Directory />
                Options none
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>


        # Access to the application itself
        #
        ProxyPassMatch /(.*) http://confluence.example.com:8090/$1
        ProxyPassReverse / http://confluence.example.com:8090/
        ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain confluence.example.com confluence.example.com


        # Logging
        #
        ServerSignature On

        LogLevel warn rewrite:debug
        ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /home/www/confluence.example.com/logs/%Y/%m/%d/secure-error.log"
        CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /home/www/confluence.example.com/logs/%Y/%m/%d/secure-access.log" combined

        #RewriteLogLevel 1
        #RewriteLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /home/www/confluence.example.com/logs/%Y/%m/%d/secure-rewrite.log"


        # SSL
        #
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile      "...crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   "...key"
        SSLCertificateChainFile "...ca-bundle"

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The simple Redirect works in my case.  I'd like to know nonetheless why httpd is throwing an error with the Proxy directives.

Comment: @dr01 possibly because you were mixing Proxy directives with the Rewrite rules, but I don't really know without spending time digging.

Comment: That's possible, but this config worked in Apache v2.2.